# Permuation and combination,Problem On selection,Circular arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

If there are $10$ points on a circle in how many ways can $4$ points be selected such that no two of them are adjacent.

Thanks

My attempt:

Number of ways of selecting $4$ points such that no two are together is same as number of ways of placing $4$ between $6$.

So my answer is $C^6_4$ which is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! I've looked at your previous questions, and I'd suggest that you state what you've tried briefly, and not just the question, because we can help you understand far better if we know exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "b/w"? If you mean "4 between 6", then you won't get $\binom{6}{4}$. Also, it's not the same as what you want. Consider smaller examples like 5 points and choosing 2 non-adjacent.

Comment: yes from the example only i came to know my answer is wrong.

Comment: Okay let's try the simpler problem where the points are on a line instead of a circle. Say 7 points and choose 3 non-adjacent. Are you able to list all the solutions out?

Comment: yes answer would be 5 C 3?

Comment: Why? What's your reasoning? If it's an intuitive guess, it's a good one, compare the list of solutions to that for 5 points choosing 3 where adjacent choices are allowed. Does it look like there is a one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: i have used the reverse method of placing to do this.

Comment: If by "reverse method of placing" you mean "choosing from the dividers", it gives the correct answer but you should still list out solutions to get a feel for the actual structure of the original problem. No point just getting the answer without knowing why it is that way. And if you follow the hint user84413 provided, he has cut the circle between two points and now it's a line, so it becomes the problem on the line, which you know how to solve, except that you've to exclude choosing both the first and last on the line, since they would be adjacent on the circle.

Answer (score 2):

You can put 6 sticks, representing the points you are not choosing, in a row.  Now you can choose 4 of the gaps created by the sticks in which to put the chosen points in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways; but since the points are in a circle instead of a line, you must subtract the number of ways you can end up choosing the two outside gaps as two of the 4 gaps, which is $\binom{5}{2}$.

Therefore there are $\binom{7}{4}-\binom{5}{2}=35-10=25$ possibilities.

$-----------------------------------------$

An alternate approach, which generalizes more readily, is to first put 4 dots (representing the points chosen) in a row.  Since we do not want these points to be consecutive, we set aside 3 sticks (as blockers) to be inserted at the end.  This leaves 3 sticks (representing the remaining points), and there are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to arrange the 4 dots and 3 sticks in order.

Since the points are in a circle, we need to subtract the number of arrangements with no stick before the first dot or after the last dot, which is simply the number of ways to arrange the 3 sticks and the 2 other dots, or $\binom{5}{2}$.

Therefore there are $\binom{7}{3}-\binom{5}{2}=35-10=25$ possibilities.

Comment: can you give the exact solution please.

Comment: Just a small note, this approach is elegant but only works for "at least 1 in-between". The general "at least $k$ in-between" requires either grouping chosen with adjacent non-chosen or the algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's label the points by $\mathbb{Z}_{10}=\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$.  Given any good choice of $4$ points, we have $4$ "selected unselected" pairs $(i,i+1)$, as illustrated below.

[image]

We can insert the remaining unselected points in $3$ inequivalent ways between the pairs: the one depicted above (where the remaining unselected points are separated by one pair), and

[image]

(where the remaining unselected points are separated by two pairs)

and

[image]

(where the remaining unselected points are adjacent).

[We can cross-check this by considering group actions.  There are $5^2=25$ ways to insert the two unselected points between the four pairs (ignoring rotations) which can be recovered by cyclically rotating the above cases: these have orbits of size $10$, $5$ and $10$, respectively, and since $10+5+10=25$, we have confirmed there are no more cases.]

Comment: This is for the problem where rotations are counted as identical. But the problem AJ_ is asking is where the points on the circle are distinct.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  But, in any case, that's covered by the second part of my answer.